# How does this getRight :: Either a b -> Maybe b work?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, do-notation

At [HaskellWiki's *Do notation considered harmful*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/index.php?title=Do_notation_considered_harmful&oldid=55588), section *Useful applications*, I found:

> It shall be mentioned that the do sometimes takes the burden from you
>   to write boring things.
>
> E.g. in
>
> ```
> getRight :: Either a b -> Maybe b
> getRight y =
>    do Right x <- y
>       return x
> ```
>
> a `case` on y is included, which calls fail if y is not a Right (i.e.
>   Left), and thus returns Nothing in this case.

Calling `fail` (`Nothing`) on a pattern mismatch sounds interesting, so I wanted to try this out. However, the syntax looks wrong - we're not in the `Either` monad, so how can we extract anything from `y`?

Indeed, I tried and it gave me "*Couldn't match type `Either a' with `Maybe'*". So let's use the correct pattern matcher, `let` in here:

```
getRight y = do { let (Right x) = y; return x }
```

That gave me a syntax error "*parse error on input `}'*". Not that I understand why this doesn't work, but let's write it out in multiline notation:

```
getRight y = do
    let (Right x) = y
    return x
```

Ah, that seemed to work - parse at least. However:

```
*Main> getRight (Right 5)
Just 5
*Main> getRight (Left 5)
Just *** Exception: […]\test.hs:16:13-25: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (Data.Either.Right x)
-- `Nothing` was expected
```

What gives? So my questions are now:

- What happened here? Why did my semicolon-brace line not work?
- How to do it correctly (with `do`, everything else is trivial)?

Comment: The parse error on `getRight` is because in general, once you switch to explicit braces and semicolons, then all language constructs that are nested inside must use explicit braces and semicolons as well: `getRight y = do { let { Right x = y }; return x }`

Comment: @kosmikus: Hm, with that I'm getting a "*parse error on input \`='*"

Comment: No idea. Works for me using ghc-7.4.2, ghc-7.6.3, and ghc-7.8.1-rc1 ...

Comment: @kosmikus: Uh, never mind. Total beginner mistake: I forgot the first `let` in ghci `let getRight x =` …

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The example is probably meant to be

```
getRight :: Either a b -> Maybe b
getRight y =
   do Right x <- return y -- note: return = Just
      return x
```

where the pattern match failure calls `fail = const Nothing`. It is translated into:

```
getRight y = let ok (Right x) = do {return x}
                 ok _         = fail "pattern mismatch error"
             in return y >>= ok
```

FWIW most experienced folks seem to think `fail` as a `Monad` method was a wart. Check out [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#t%3aMonadPlus) for a maybe more principled approach to failure.

Comment: That page generally has some problems... for example, whole paragraphs being outdated with a footnote saying that they're outdated (why not just remove it then?).

Comment: So only `<-` notation does call `fail` on pattern mismatch, `let` doesn't? Could you maybe show the code that the compiler generates when de-sugaring the `do`?